# A Perfect Hashing Function for an 8 by 8 board?

Tags: theory, hash

I'm implementing a board with only 2 types of pieces, and was looking for a function to map from that board to a Long Integer (64 bits). I was thinking this should not be so hard, since a long integer contains more available information than an 8 by 8 array (call it grid[x][y]) with only 3 possible elements in each spot including the empty element. I tried the following:
(1) Zobrist hashing with Longs rather than ints (Just to test - I didn't actually expect that to work perfectly)
(2) Translated the grid into a 64 character string of a base 3 number, and then took that number and parsed it into a long. I think this should work, but it took a very very long time.
Is there some simpler solution to (2) involving bit operations of shifting or something like that?
Edit: Please don't give me actual code, as this is for a class project, and that would probably be considered unethical in our department (or at least not in Java).
Edit2: Basically, there are only 10 whites and 10 blacks on the board at any given time, of which no two pieces of the same color can be neighbors, either in the horizontal, vertical, or diagonal direction. Also, there are 12 spaces for each color where only that color may place pieces.

Comment: Perfect hashing is used when you have a predefined input and need to map a short value to a finished output. In your case it seems more like you are looking for an encoding scheme to store your values in.

You have 8 * 8 cells, each with 3 different values. which is too much for 64 bit without a compression scheme. It is however hard to say what a good algorithm would be without knowing more about how many pieces there and be, or how they can be distributed on the board.

Comment: Obviously your edit makes a difference to the question. But why insist on a 64 bit int?

Comment: Well I guess I wouldn't mind using a larger object if necessary. Just hoping to make it as small as possible so not as to get an out of memory error.

Comment: And also I wanted to avoid using massive amounts of computational resources on the hashing function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each tile in the game can be 1 of any 3 states at any point in the game, then the minimum amount of storage required for a "perfect hash" when hashing every possible state of the game board, at any given moment will 
 = power(3,8*8) individual hashes 
 = [log2(3^64)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log2%283%5E64%29) bits 
 = approx. 101.4 bits, so you will need at least 102 bits to store this info

At this point, you may as well just say there are 4 states for each tile, which will bring you to needing [128 bits](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log2%284%5E64%29).

Once you do this, its rather easy to make a fast hashing algorithm for the board.

E.g. (writtin as c++, may need to alter code if the platform doesn't support 128 bit numbers)

`uint_128 CreateGameBoardHash(int (&game_board)[8][8])
{
    uint_128  board_hash = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
        {
            board_hash |= game_board[i][j] << ((i * 8 + j) *2);
        }
    }
    return board_hash;
}`

This method will only waste 26 bits (little more than 3 bytes) over the optimal solution of 102 bits, but you will save a LOT of processing time that would be otherwise spent doing base 3 math.

---

**Edit** Here's a version that doesn't require 128 bits and should work on any 16-bit (or better) processor

`struct GameBoardHash
{
    uint16 row[8];
};`

GameBoardHash CreateGameBoardHash(int (&game_board)[8][8])
{
    GameBoardHash board_hash;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        board_hash.row[i] = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
        {
            board_hash.row[i] |= game_board[j] << (j*2);
        }
    }
    return board_hash;
}

Comment: Of course, you might be able to get a more optimal solution if you take into account the adjacency rules and piece limits that you specified in "edit2", but this also makes it much more difficult to work out an algorithm that will work efficiently (both memory and cpu usage).

Answer (score 0):

It won't fit into a 64 bit integer. You have 64 squares and you need more than 1 bit to record each square. Why do you need it to fit into a 64 bit int? Are you targetting the ZX81?

Comment: Well what happened was that we used a single board object for an entire tree search of say 100,000 board possibilities. Whenever we got to an attemptedMove, we simply temporarily applied that move, and backtracked out using an undoMove. To hash the board, I used a hashCode that took into account the current position of the board, say Hashtable.put(board1,score), but the problem was, that whenever there was a collision, it would think board1 = thisBoard since it stored a pointer to board1 == thisBoard (since we never create a new Board object, only edit the existing one).

Comment: To corret this, I was hoping to instead hash a unique value, say Hashtable.put(board1.UniqueNumber(), score), and use a Hashtable.get(this.UniqueNumber(), score), which would eliminate collisions all together, and any problems that would occur.

Comment: +1 for mention of ZX81, -1 because ZX81 ints were 16 bits. :)

Comment: @Gabe the ZX81 had very limited RAM; -1 for you for not realising that was my point!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about a 16 byte array containing the bits? Each 2-bits, represent a position's value, so that given a position in the 8x8 board (pos=0-63), you can figure out the index by dividing pos by 4 and you can get the value by doing bit manipulation to get two bits (bit0=pos mod 4 and bit1=bit0 + 1). The two bits can be either 00, 01, or 10.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comments to David, it doesn't seem like you really need a perfect hash value. You just need a hashable object.

Make it simple for yourself... Make some hash for you position in the overwrite to GetHashCode(), and then do the rest of the work in the Equals function.

If you REALLY need it to be perfect, then you have to use a GUID to encode your data in and make your own hash that can use 128bit keys. But that is just a huge investment of time for little benifit.

Comment: I tried making hashable objects which contained a copy of the current piecesArray, but ran into out of JVM out of memory issues, after storing about 200k of these objects, though otherwise this approach did work.

Comment: 200k objects? Thats nothing, so you are wasting a ton of memory somewhere. With a int[8][8] you are using 256 bytes, plus lets say the same in overhead. For 200k objects, thats just around 100mb.